# CakePHP App::Import wont work

Tags: cakephp, import, vendor

I'm trying to load a vendor lib to one of my components using App:Import, which doesn't seem to work :(. But following require_once statement works fine, and it loads the file with no issues.

```
require_once('../../vendor/myvendor/somefile.php');
```

Then I tried with following App::imports didnt work.

```
App::import('Vendor', 'myvendor', array('file' => 'myvendor/somefile.php'));
```

And then tried following, but didn't work either,

```
App::import('Vendor', 'myvendor', array('file' => 'somefile.php'));
```

Any ideas whats I'm missing here?

P.S : This file doesn't have a class. So not trying to auto load the class.

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to work". Do you get an error? Is something not executed in the background? We'll need some more information to troubleshoot this issue. The syntax of the import itself is correct, so that's unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: So, lets say there is a function in somefile.php call function test(). so if I try to call test() in my component class, it says undefined function. This is when I use import, but if I use require_once it works fine.

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer for this?